# maps on iOS 8 when launching a map select which map app use

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

Is there any way to when launching a map if the user has more than one map app(native iOS Map and google maps) have some sort of prompt to select the map app you want to open it? or do I need to create specific methods for each map app that I have installed on the device.

Comment: What do you mean by launch a map? Do you mean open another map application from your app?

Comment: For example I have an address and I want to to use a map to get the directions but the device has ios maps and google maps, is there a way to prompt a message to select which app I want to use(ios maps or google maps) to get directions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the GUI yourself, but these are basically what you need to do. They are relatively simple:

1. Set up the URL (assume you have `lat`, `lon`):

   For apple map

   ```
   NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%.5f,%.5f", 
                                                          lat, lon];
   ```

   For google map

   ```
   NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%.5f,%.5f", 
                                                          lat, lon];
   ```

   or other maps...
2. Then, open it

   ```
   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're making about your own apps, you can use the [URL Scheme](http://pureoxygenlabs.com/googles-new-maps-ios-app-and-url-scheme/) on iOS to open the Google Maps app, perhaps add some [deep linking](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/deep-link) too.

But if you're talking about opening the maps from contacts, or the notes app, you might need to
[Make Google Maps your default maps app on iOS with MapsOpener tweak](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/make-google-maps-your-default-maps-app-on-ios-with-mapsopener-tweak)